# Why isn't the straightforward translation made here?

Tags: traducción

In the spanish translaton of Twain's *Adventures of Huckleberry Finn*, the following paragraph:

> "What! and I as high as a tree and as big as a church? All right,
> then; I WOULD come; but I lay I'd make that man climb the highest tree
> there was in the country."

...is translated as:

> ––¡Cómo! ¿Si yo fuera igual de alto que un árbol y cuadrado como un
> armario de tres cuerpos? Bueno, vale; iría, pero te apuesto a que ese
> hombre tendría que subirse al árbol más alto que hubiera en todo el
> país.

Here “as big as a church” is translated as “cuadrado como un armario de tres cuerpos" ("square like a three-body closet” according to google translate). What?!? Why? What’s wrong with “tan grande como una iglesia”?

### UPDATE

To answer pablod76, here is the previous spot where the size of a church is mentioned:

> "Why," said he, "a magician could call up a lot of genies, and they
> would hash you up like nothing before you could say Jack Robinson.
> They are as tall as a tree and as big around as a church."
>
> ––Hombre ––dijo––, un mago puede llamar a un montón de genios, que te
> podrían hacer picadillo en medio minuto. Son igual de altos que
> árboles y cuadrados como armarios de tres cuerpos.

So, it is translated in pretty much the same way (*cuadrados como armarios de tres cuerpos*)

Comment: As far as comparing something to the size of a church, I have heard a madrileña say: *Es una mentira tan grande como una catedral*. But *iglesias* come in all shapes and sizes, and since Spanish-speakers tend to live among many churches, it might not be as descriptive as it is to a native English-speaker. There may be other cultural notions which led the translator to choose to avoid the church comparison.

Comment: What does the translation say a few paragraphs before that, where the original says «“Why,” said he, “a magician could call up a lot of genies, and they would hash you up like nothing before you could say Jack Robinson. They are as tall as a tree and as big around as a church.”»?

Comment: @pablodf76: See my Update

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Thanks. At least the translator was consistent.

Comment: La traducción al español fue realizado por una persona de España o de alguno de los países de América que habla español nativamente?
Esto influye en la manera de traducir modismos y giros del idioma original al español

Comment: Concuerdo con @nopaltepec que las iglesias en los países que hablan español nativamente son edificaciones de diferentes tamaños.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that a Spanish speaker would use 'iglesia' to describe a giant person unless buildings have been mentioned(as tall as the Twin Towers, as tall as a giraffe, as tall as a mountain)

"Como un ropero/armario de tres cuerpos" means "as big as a cupboard/closet/truck/whale/barrel/phone booth", and refers to a person as broad chest, bulky, broad-shouldered, corpulent or fat in a bad or funny way.

Maybe he's like a wide bodied giant is more appropriate.

Comment: A few paragraphs before this snippet, Huck reports Tom explaining about genies: “They are as tall as a tree and as big around as a church.” I wonder what the translator did there. I tried looking whether this was an idiom, but it doesn't look like it. *“Grande como un ropero”* was a simile my father used to make about well-built people. Specifying *“de tres cuerpos”* seems to me rather excessive.

Comment: "ropero de tres cuerpos" is not so common, but it is still in use. If you want to emphasize the size.